# Grid Layout not changing when changing screen size, Media Queries CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to get elements from being in 2 columns to 1 when changing to a smaller screen size using display:grid and Media Query. Furthermore, despite using fr units it doesn't get smaller with the screen size after certain value and it shows horizontal scrolling which I dont want. But I cannot understand why it doesn't work, have already spent several hours looking for helpful information.

```css
*{max-width:100%;}
      #grid {
        display: grid;
        height: 200px;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    
      }
    
      #item1 {
        grid-column:2;
        background-color: lime;
      }
    
      #item2 {
        grid-column:2;
        background-color: yellow;
        grid-row: 2;
      }
    
      #item3 {
        grid-column:2;
        background-color: blue;
        grid-row: 3;
      }
    #item4 {
        grid-column:2;
        background-color: green;
        grid-row: 4;
      }
    @media all and(min-width:500px){
        #grid {
          height: 200px;
          grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    
        }
          #item1 {
          grid-column:2;
         
        }
    
        #item2 {
          grid-column:4;
       
        grid-row:1;
        }
    
        #item3 {
          grid-column:2;
   
          grid-row: 3;
        }
        #item4 {
          grid-column:4;

          grid-row: 3;
        }
      }
```

```html
  <div id="grid">
    <div id="item1"></div>
    <div id="item2"></div>
    <div id="item3"></div>
    <div id="item4"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hey dude, based on your code, I can see that you don't have a good understanding of some concepts like media queries and css grid. So, while you have used stack this time, I suggest that you look up a good tutorial and learn the fundamentals. Also, your question is a bit unclear

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is a simple space between the parenthesis containing the `min-width` size and the `and` -> `@media all and (min-width: 500px)` instead of `@media all and(min-width: 500px)`

```css
*{max-width:100%;}
      #grid {
        display: grid;
        height: 200px;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    
      }
    
      #item1 {
        grid-column:2;
        background-color: lime;
      }
    
      #item2 {
        grid-column:2;
        background-color: yellow;
        grid-row: 2;
      }
    
      #item3 {
        grid-column:2;
        background-color: blue;
        grid-row: 3;
      }
    @media all and (min-width: 500px){
        #grid {
          height: 200px;
          grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    
        }
          #item1 {
          grid-column:2;
          background-color: lime;
        }
    
        #item2 {
          grid-column:4;
          background-color: yellow;
        grid-row:1;
        }
    
        #item3 {
          grid-column:2;
          background-color: blue;
          grid-row: 3;
        }
        #item4 {
          grid-column:4;
          background-color: blue;
          grid-row: 3;
        }
      }
```

```html
<div id="grid">
    <div id="item1"></div>
    <div id="item2"></div>
    <div id="item3"></div>
    <div id="item4"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I can see the elements in 2 per row, but when I resize the window they don't go in 1 column. What could be wrong?

Comment: Not sure, the example is working... make sure to study everything in detail on your end.

Answer (score 0):

I can't completely understand why, but assigning these properties to the meta tag solved the problem: `name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"`

More info: [The Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)

So here is why: [Explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag)